# When was Superman's backstory and the fate of his parents revealed?

Tags: dc, comics, superman, history-of

I was pondering the issue of why so many superheroes are orphans, which led me to consider who was first identified as an orphan and when.  Although Batman was probably hot on Superman's heels, I assume that Supes was identified as an orphan first, since he came first, and since his powers made his origin story more important.

I found this picture of Superman's parents watching his spacecraft leave Krypton:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Was this the moment when we learned that Kal-El's mother and father perished on his home world?  If so, when did this issue appear?  If not, when did we discover Kal-El's status as an orphan?

Comment: Should I take the green check mark to mean that the year 1948, not 1940, is when Superman's backstory and the fate of his parents were (or was) revealed?

Comment: @user14111 The green checkmark is the asker's way of determining the best answer to their question, in their opinion. It could be that Wad accepted the answer before you posted yours, it could be that he meant specifically in the comics (note the "comics" tag at the bottom of the question), or it could be that he accepted it for some other reason.

Comment: @TylerH You may be right. Personally, I consider the radio program more important than the comic books. When I was a kid, I listened to *Superman* on the radio regularly, but I seldom had a dime to buy a comic book.

Comment: @user14111 - I was asking about the comics specifically, so I accepted the answer about the comics.  Your answer deserves its own reward, so you will get a bounty as soon as I can open one (48 hours after the question was posted).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. No need for a bounty.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### Our first exposure to Jor-El and Lara being shown sending baby Kal-el to Earth was in 1948 in Superman #53 by Bill Finger and Wayne Boring. This is almost a decade after Superman has been saving the day. It was implied in some earlier depictions (particularly in radio broadcasts) but never actually realized "in print" until Superman #53.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- This origin was revised in 1961 in Superman #146 (by Otto Binder and Al Plastino), we saw that origin again, but refined and changed just a bit...

[image]

[image]

[image]

The scene depicted by the original post originated in the World of Krypton series #3, in 1979. Cover art by Ross Andru and Dick Giordano.

[image]

- "The Last Days of Krypton" written by Paul Kupperberg, penciled by Howard Chaykin, inked by Frank Chiaramonte, colored by Jerry Serpe and lettered by Ben Oda.

Comment: I love that even in a world where people are super smart and learn calculus as 4 year old's, there are science deniers

Comment: I always thought it was a little strange, personally, to find people who were supposedly so intelligent and yet unwilling to even consider their planet's impeding demise. I've been working on a story to explain WHY the Kryptonians didn't leave. It would never be published but it would make everything about the end of the Kryptonians, the existence of the Daxamites, and why so many humanoids species have superpowers in the 30th century.

Comment: @Thaddeus: It's not strange at all. To quote Upton Sinclair: "It is difficult to get a man to understand something, when his salary depends upon his not understanding it!". Seriously, this. Very smart people can find very smart counter-arguments to anything

Comment: The 1948 story loses all credibility in the penultimate panel, when Lara refuses to accompany little Kal-El in the spaceship, although there is room for both of them. She sacrifices her own life in order to . . . send her child ***all alone*** on a space voyage to another planet?

Comment: Cultural differences: we could not understand her motivations.

Comment: It looks like we also have Superman defined as human.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze I wonder if you noticed in the second attachment of your answer the comment "Why, they do not even possess X-ray vision"?

Answer (score 38):

**The fate of Superman's parents** was revealed on **February 12, 1940,** with the broadcast of "The Baby from Krypton", first episode of the *Superman* [radio serial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Superman_(radio)). It is quite clear from the broadcast, which you can listen to at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/superman_otr/Superman_400212_01_The_Baby_From_Kry.mp3) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIYbe6vtyJE), that Jor-El and Lara did not survive the end of Krypton:

> So the tiny rocket ship roars into the uncharted heavens as the mighty planet of Krypton explodes into millions of glowing fragments, glittering stars to remain forever in the night sky. **Jor-El and Lara, devoted parents of the tiny boy, perish in the giant quake that destroys Krypton.**
>   
> But what of the rocket ship? Does it reach the earth? Does it find its mark in all the far-flung darkness of space? Remember—don't miss the next installment of *Superman!*

**Batman's status as an orphan** was established a few months earlier. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman#Early_years), Batman's origin story appeared in *Detective Comics* #33, the **November 1939** issue:

> The character's origin was revealed in #33 (Nov. 1939), unfolding in a two-page story that establishes the brooding persona of Batman, a character driven by the death of his parents. Written by Finger, it depicts a young Bruce Wayne witnessing his parents' murder at the hands of a mugger. Days later, at their grave, the child vows that "by the spirits of my parents [I will] avenge their deaths by spending the rest of my life warring on all criminals".

Comment: Was it invented for the radio and only later "backported" to the comics, then?

Comment: @Random832 Could be, I don't know. I guess it depends on how much was explained about Superman's origin in the first couple years of the comic book.

Answer (score 4):

Batman was first introduced in 1939. In 1938, the very first panel of the very first published Superman story, in Action Comics #1, it very clearly states:“As a distant planet was destroyed by old age, a scientist placed his infant son within his hastily devised space-ship, launching it toward Earth!” While the finer details of this were not revealed until later, I would say that this proves that Superman was shown as orphan before Batman was.

[image: Action Comics 1]

Comment: It says that the planet is being "destroyed by old age". It doesn't confirm the status of his parents, though.

Comment: @Richard - Pretty sure their deaths are heavily implied, as the entire planet is being destroyed, and his space-ship is described as "hastily devised", meaning they probably didn't have time to build others for the rest of them.  Interesting how they basically give his entire back story in one page.  They didn't waste time back in the day...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Heavily implied, yes. Stated? Nope.

Comment: @Richard By the same token, the 1948 and 1961 comic book stories posted in Thaddeus's answer merely **imply** that Krypton really blew up as predicted, and that Jor-el and Kara and all the other Kryptonians perished. Those events are neither depicted nor stated to have occurred. They were **predicted** by Jor-El, but he could have been wrong.

Comment: @user14111 - While you're not wrong, both of his examples actually show the catastophe, rather than just a description.

Comment: @Richard What I see in those comics is a severe and damaging quake afflicting one locality on the planet. Aside from Jor-El's alarmist ravings, there's no reason to believe that the whole planet is going to explode, or even that there will be no survivors in, uh, Krypton City or whatever that place is called.

Comment: His adoptive parents died in page 2.